# (Trivial?) C# namespace/class hierarchy problem

Tags: c#

I am somewhat new to C# and I am puzzled by a compilation result belonging to a VERY small, simple and transparent program I have written and which is part of a university project. The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Hemtenta_problem_1
{
    public class Basklass
    { 
        public virtual void SkrivTrams()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hej Hopp");
        }
    }
    public class Avledd_klass : Basklass
    {   
                    public override void SkrivTrams()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hej Hå");
        }
    }
    public class Avledd_klass_till : Avledd_klass
    {
        public new virtual void SkrivTrams()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tjo Hej");
        }
    }
    public class Ytterligare_avledd_klass : Avledd_klass
    {

    }_ //row which gives compiler message

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler's message, relating to the row with the comment, is

> A namespace cannot directly contain
>   members such as fields or methods

Now, I perfectly well understand that any field or method can't be placed out there "in the open". It needs to be part of a class, and inside one. BUT IT IS NOT A FIELD OR A METHOD THAT I AM CODING, IT IS A CLASS IN ITSELF. None of the other classes, above in the code, gave this problem. It started when I wrote the very last and as yet empty class.

Is Visual Studio's compiler working right? Or what is it in 40-odd lines that I am not seeing? Very grateful for comments that could help.

Comment: What is that underscore in the line you get the error?

Comment: I have tried your exact code and it works for me. (Bar the underscore at the end of Ytterligare_avledd_klass class) EDIT: YEah the underscore is the problem!

Comment: There are just too many underscores in your code in general. [Naming guidelines for the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xhs4564.aspx) recommend Pascal-casing class and method names, rather than using underscores. Change your naming style, and that should help stave off those stray underscores.

Comment: As far as I remember it was said in `Code complete` that each year compilers become more and more clean (in terms of bugs) but developers are continuing blaming compilers.

Comment: It is a very commendable idea to name classes Pascal-style, only this time the specs happened to be that class names should be readable Swedish sentences. But the stray underscore came from all those underscores that I wrote. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You have an `_` after your closing `}` on the line where you have put your error code.  You need to remove it.

Comment: Certainly - I now notice that the fault lies with me and the typo of the underscore on the line. IntelliSense put a tilde on top of the underscore, so I missed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I want to say "close but no cigar" @Santillana